# What do we do about duplicate questions that are not closed?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I have previously added similar answers to duplicate questions. I did this because duplicate questions seem to occur frequently and do not get closed even when I flag them as duplicates.

[image]

What are we to do in cases like this where clear duplicates aren't marked or closed as such and continue to live on?

Are we allowed to add similar answers to duplicate questions so that everyone can get to see the answer?

Answer (score 5):

I guess that posts originate from Stack Overflow where there is a massive backlog on the Close Vote review queue.

The best thing still is to close those posts. That will help that user and other users to find the (better) canonical answer(s). It is hard however to get them closed if no one else votes on them.

The best option you have is to find support on the closing of that post. Some sites have dedicated chat rooms for moderation / closing posts, for example the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) on Stack Overflow. I guess other sites have similar chat rooms. (Read their rules carefully, I failed to do so once, and they don't like it)

If that doesn't help or you can't find support for it, just leave it as-is. Maybe someone will pick up your automatic close vote comment and will re-initiate the closing process at another time. At least the comment will help future readers.

Comment: So the "only" thing I can really do is to vote to close it, and THEN go into a chatroom and beg for others to vote on it too?
That seems like "cheating the system"?

Comment: No, that is not cheating. It is keeping the site clean. If you do it because you don't like that particular user it is cheating. And indeed, you are possibly taking close votes away from other posts if all the users in that chat room use all their close votes for that day, which is unlikely.